# Convert a string to list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, string

I want to convert `"30 20 10"` into `["30","20","10"]` etc.
I tried `[int(i) for i in str.split(' ')]` but this gives me `[30,20,10]` not `["30","20","10"]`

Comment: `"30 20 10".split()`

Comment: Your problem obviously lies in adding that `int(..)` if you wanted *strings*.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do not use list comprehension until you are more comfortable with python. Furthermore, you should show code in a block so we can know the name of the variable you are using.

```
var_str = "30 20 10"
list_str = var_str.split(' ')
print(list_str)
['30', '20', '10']
```